# getbundle is null when starting previous activity through intent

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activity's in my code FirstActivity and SecondActivity.

From FirstActivity I start SecondActivity see code below

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("text", "someValue");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
```

and this works ok, i can read the value in SecondActivity i have added in putExtra in FirstActivity.

From SecondActivity i have some complicated code but in some place i need to start FirstActivity and i do it by following code

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), FirstActivity);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

            /* tested with both bundle and put extra none of them worked
            */
            bundle.putString("text2", "someOtherString");
            intent.putExtra("text3", "someOtherString");                 
            intent.putExtras(bundle);

            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
```

This start FirstActivity but when i check the code (in FirstActivity)

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent != null) {
        String string, string2;

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if(bundle != null) {
            string = bundle.getString("text2"); //return empty
        }
        string2 = intent.getStringExtra("text3") //returns empty

    }

}
```

I can not understand why it is empty?
Should i start the activities with different flags? If yes please explain why.

Comment: Please cleanup your second block of code - it has either typo mistakes or actual mistakes that are causing the behavior you observe (create intent2? fill intent1? fill intent..)

Comment: It was typo mistakes. Thank you for your observation. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

You need an interface in secondActivity and implement it in firstActivity. Because your logic from second to first is wrong.

Comment: What do you mean that the logic from second to first is wrong? Why do i need an interface? Are you mixing this with action-fragment communication

Comment: Just implement interface and you will see the reaults

Comment: It was one of the lowest quality answer i have ever seen here. What kind of interface? What kind of problem will this solve? The data between activities is send between bundles so i do not really understand what do you mean. Sometimes no answer is better than a wrong or short answer